# new content type, with completely blank(body of node only) output theme files

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type that is only used for scripts on my drupal site that should return json data.  So the issue then becomes that I can't have any of the theming elements of the site in the output.

So I know I need blank (only the output variable) tpl files for the following:
html.tpl.php
page.tpl.php
region.tpl.php
block.tpl.php
field.tpl.php (the manual says this isn't used but its the only way I could find to remove field divs around the body of my page)

So my question is, how can I create all of the content specific files for this content type? I know its easy to do a theme override in template.php BUT I can only get it to work for html.tpl,page.tpl and thats it.  Drupal seems to ignore any content specific functions from region down to field.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you tagged this drupal-7, which I haven't tried yet.  But, in Drupal 6 I would accomplish this by adding a new page template to $vars['template_files'][] in the page preprocess function of template.php.  Example:

```
$node_type = $vars['node']->type;
if ($node_type == '{your content type name here}') {
  $vars['template_files'][] = "page-" . $node_type;
}
```

If your content type was called 'scripts', then Drupal will look for a page called page-scripts.tpl.php, which will contain only one line:

```
<?php print $content; ?>
```